# Encadeamento de Promise/Observable em IONIC/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic3, promises

Pessoal sou novo em IONIC/Angular e não entendi ainda muito bem Promise/Observable e gostaria de uma ajuda !
Tenho a seguinte situação:

1. Usuário clica em um botão que irá buscar informações no SQLite do celular;
2. É feito um foreach no retorno e chamado uma WebApi (http post) passando para cada registro a API;
3. Ao terminar o foreach irei executar 2 comandos para deletar as tabelas do SQLite;
4. E finalmente dar uma mensagem ao usuário

Porém não consigo definir essa sequencia, no meu código ele deleta, da a mensagem ao usuário para depois chamar a API para cada registro. Segue abaixo trecho do código

```
    SincronizarSistema() {
  let loading: Loading = this.showLoading('Sincronizando...');

  this.voucherService.sincronizarPedidoDetalheSistema()

  this.pedidosDetalhe = [];
  this.pedidosDetalheBase = [];
  this.carregarEventos();
  loading.dismiss();

  this.showAlert('Sincronização realizada com sucesso !')}
```

---

```
sincronizarPedidoDetalheSistema() {
 this.getDB().then(() => {
  let listaPedidosDetalhe: PedidoDetalhe[];

  this.retornaPedidosDetalheBaixados()
    .then((pedidosDetalhe: PedidoDetalhe[]) => {

      listaPedidosDetalhe = pedidosDetalhe

      listaPedidosDetalhe.forEach(element => {
        this.baixaPedidoDetalheSistema(element.idPedidoDetalhe)
          .subscribe(pedidoDetalhe => {
            console.log(`Pedido ${element.idPedidoDetalhe} baixado com sucesso !`)
          }, error => {
            console.log('Erro ao baixar pedido ', error)
          })
      });


      console.log("chegou aqui")
      this.db.executeSql('DELETE FROM tblPedidoDetalhe', [])
      this.db.executeSql('DELETE FROM tblEventoSincronismo', [])

    })
});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer utilizando forkJoin, porém fiz um teste em um emulador desligando a internet (que neste caso daria erro por não conseguir acessar a API) e não caiu no catch

```
 this.voucherService.retornaPedidosDetalheBaixados()
    .then((pedidosDetalhe: PedidoDetalhe[]) => {
      this.pedidosDetalheBaixados = pedidosDetalhe
    })
    .then(() => {
      if (this.pedidosDetalheBaixados.length > 0) {
        const calls = [];

        this.pedidosDetalheBaixados.forEach((pedidoDetalhe: PedidoDetalhe) => {
          calls.push(this.voucherService.baixaPedidoDetalheSistema(pedidoDetalhe.idPedidoDetalhe))
        })
        return forkJoin(calls)
          .subscribe((sucess) => {
            this.voucherService.deletaBases();
            this.pedidosDetalhe = [];
            this.pedidosDetalheBase = [];
            this.carregarEventos();
            loading.dismiss();

            this.messageService.showToast('Sincronização realizada com sucesso !', '3000', 'bottom').subscribe(toast => { });
          },(erro) =>{
            this.messageService.showAlert('Não foi possível realizar e sincronização com o sistema')
          })
      } else {
        this.voucherService.deletaBases();
        this.pedidosDetalhe = [];
        this.pedidosDetalheBase = [];
        this.carregarEventos();
        loading.dismiss();

        this.messageService.showToast('Sincronização realizada com sucesso !', '3000', 'bottom').subscribe(toast => { });;
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.messageService.showAlert('Não foi possível realizar e sincronização com o sistema')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, boa noite.

tente assim:

```
listaPedidosDetalhe.forEach(element => {
    this.baixaPedidoDetalheSistema(element.idPedidoDetalhe)
      .subscribe(pedidoDetalhe => {
        console.log(`Pedido ${element.idPedidoDetalhe} baixado com sucesso !`)
        this.db.executeSql('DELETE FROM tblPedidoDetalhe', []);
        this.db.executeSql('DELETE FROM tblEventoSincronismo', [])!`);
      }, error => {
        console.log('Erro ao baixar pedido ', error)
      })
  });
```

Comment: Este caso até funcionaria, porém eu iria deletar as bases mais de uma vez sem necessidade (processamento sem necessidade)